# How to move the Index and Query role to another server?

Tags: search, migration, crawling

I want to move the Index & Query role from a server to another server in the same SharePoint 2007 Farm, how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Parts of this guide can be useful in your situation, check [Add servers to farm](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262079%28office.12%29.aspx#section8) section.